# How do I get Data from a USB acceleration sensor that pretends to be a Mircophone?

Tags: android, audio, usb, sensors, microphone

this is my first app and I'm trying to get data from a sensor.
The sensor is a [Digiducer](https://digiducer.com/) and according to their website it uses generic USB Audio Drivers.

> No drivers or DLL’s required! USB Audio drivers are standard in most operating systems (iOS, Windows, MacOS, Android) [LINK](https://digiducer.com/pages/software-developers)

I've read the [USB Digital Audio Article](https://source.android.com/devices/audio/usb) and it says that I don't need any specific driver to be installed, if the device is class compliant (which it claims to be).

> The term driverless is a common synonym for class compliant, indicating that it is possible to use the standard features of such a peripheral without requiring an operating-system specific driver to be installed. [LINK](https://source.android.com/devices/audio/usb#class)

I checked all conditions mentioned in the chapter [Android support for USB audio class](https://source.android.com/devices/audio/usb#androidSupport) and the sensor matches them perfectly

> Android 5.0 (API level 21) and above supports a subset of USB audio class 1 (UAC1) features:
>   - The Android device must act as host
>   - The audio format must be PCM (interface type I)
>   - The bit depth must be 16-bits, 24-bits, or 32-bits where 24 bits of useful audio data are left-justified within the most significant bits of the 32-bit word
>   - The sample rate must be either 48, 44.1, 32, 24, 22.05, 16, 12, 11.025, or 8 kHz
>   - The channel count must be 1 (mono) or 2 (stereo)

I don't understand what I have to do, to get the data from my sensor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out by myself.
Actually I had to do nothing.
I just had to call the AudioManager and search for the device name in the input devices

```
    AudioManager am = (AudioManager) getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
    AudioDeviceInfo[] adiArray = am.getDevices(1); // INPUT_DEVICES = 1

    for (AudioDeviceInfo deviceInfo : adiArray) {
        String name = deviceInfo.getProductName().toString().toLowerCase();
        if (name.contains("33d01")) {
            externalMic = deviceInfo;
            break;
        }
    }
```